# How to create a binary search tree that includes all numbers from 1 to n

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

Im trying to create a Binary search tree that includes all numbers from 1 to n. an example would be from 1 to 5 would be something like

root: 3

root.left: 2

root.left.left = 1

root.right = 4

root.right.right = 5

This tree happens to be not very balanced, but I would prefer a method that produces as balanced of a tree as possible.

I am trying to create my own data structure for this, so I basically just wrote a Node class:

```
    private class BinaryNode{
        int data;
        BinaryNode left;
        BinaryNode right;
        BinaryNode parent;
    }
```

And I planned on having that inside another class, which represents the tree itself. I am stuck finding a good way determine the left/right values appropriately to build the tree, any help is appreciated!

Comment: you would need a balanceFactor variable within your BinaryNode class so that you can balance the tree as you go along. Anyway if you want to balance the tree as you go along why not try to implement an AVL tree rather than binary search tree?

Comment: I was considering an AVL, but figured I would try this first

Comment: oh okay, i see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data on the root node would be `(n+1)/2`; if you've got a subtree representing the range `[i..j]`, the root of that subtree is `(i+j)/2` (using integer arithmetic).

You can build the tree recursively using that fact:

```
static BinaryNode build(int i, int j) {
    if (i > j) return null;

    int mid = (i + j) / 2;  // Assumes i >= 0.

    BinaryNode node = new BinaryNode();
    node.data = mid;

    node.left = build(i, mid - 1);
    if (node.left != null) node.left.parent = node;

    node.right = build(mid + 1, j);
    if (node.right != null) node.right.parent = node;

    return node;
}
```

Then start the recursive call:

```
BinaryNode node = build(1, n);
```

It must be pointed out, however, that such a binary search tree (storing contiguous integers from 1 to n) is useless: you may as well simply use an array, and "search" it using an array index.

Comment: If it is not too complicated can you show how to make a balanced binary tree starting with a sorted array of random numbers.

Comment: Almost exactly the same: `i` and `j` become a range of array indices; just pass the array as an additional parameter to `build`, and use `node.data = arr[mid];`.

Comment: Also, you'd need to start the recursion with `build(arr, 0, arr.length-1)`.

Comment: What's the `O(?)` complexity of this solution?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz O(n). It creates exactly 1 node for each element in the range. More formally, this also appears to follow from the Master Theorem: `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + const`, so `T(n) \in Theta(n^(log_2 2)) = Theta(n^1) = Theta(n)`.

Comment: Thank you! Im not sure where I was getting stuck, as your answer makes complete sense and is definitely where I was trying to go with this. As for this being useless, I was actually just practicing by writing a program that could guess a number as fast as possible, and I figured I might as well practice with trees while I was at it haha

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insert(int id){
    Node newNode = new Node(id);
    if(root==null){
        root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node current = root;
    Node parent = null;
    while(true){
        parent = current;
        if(id<current.data){                
            current = current.left;
            if(current==null){
                parent.left = newNode;
                newNode.parent = parent;
                return;
            }
        }else{
            current = current.right;
            if(current==null){
                parent.right = newNode;
                newNode.parent = parent;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without recursion insertion of 1 to n numbers.

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
    Solution2 s = new Solution2();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i = 1;i <= n;i++){
        s.insert(i);
    }

}
```