# What Data Structure should I use for log n time constrait (Java)?

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to use a data structure that can hold a set of integer. However, I need to accomplish add, return frequency of integers, search and return number of integers larger than the integer y (a parameter of the method) with the constraint that every method have to be in O(log n) time.

I plan on using Binary Search Tree so that I can easily do a search in O(log n). However, I do not know how to hold a set of integer (e.g. a list of same integers) in a BST. Can someone give some insight about the data structure to use to accomplish my big-O constraint.

Comment: You might find this related question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615150/how-to-create-a-binary-search-tree-that-includes-all-numbers-from-1-to-n

Comment: A set of integers, by definition, doesn't contain the same integer multiple times. It's unclear what you are asking. My guess is that you are looking for a multiset, which can be represented in Java by a `Map<E, Integer>`, where `E` is the type of elements (in your case integers), and the associated `Integer` value is the number of occurences of that element.

Comment: Perhaps an illustration of the problem would help?  Give us a collection of integers and some idea of what you'd want for outputs in certain situations.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: A [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) will do all these things in O(log n).